# mmap in linux-kernel with vm_insert_page()

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to understand mmap() functionality which can map page-by-page to the user space address.I am mapping these pages using the vm_insert_page(). This is returning with out any error. But when from the user space tried to write into the mapped memory, i'm getting the null pointer dereference. I am posting the code below. The system is x86,32 bit system.

The mmap() anf fault() function is posted.

```
static int mmap(struct file *filp , struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
        vma->vm_ops = &vm_ops;
        vma->vm_flags |= VM_MIXEDMAP;
        vm_open(vma);
        return 0;
}


static int vm_fault(struct vm_area_struct *vma,struct vm_fault *vmf)
{
        struct page *page=NULL;
        page = alloc_page(GFP_HIGHUSER);//Both the alloc_pages() are working fine.
        if(!page)
        {
                printk("The allocation of pagee memory is failed\n");
                return -VM_FAULT_OOM;
        }

//        get_page(page);
        if(vm_insert_page(vma,vmf->virtual_address,(page)))
                printk("Thepage table creation is failed\n");
        printk("The vm_insert of page is done\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.